# Dynamic array in c with terminator character

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic-arrays

I want to write a program that alloc a dynamic array in memory and have it keep listening for input until the value "-1". I've do this, but it uses too much memory.

```
int *a=malloc(sizeof(int));
int i=0;
int j;
while (a[i-1]!=-1){
scanf("%d",a+i);
i++;
a=realloc(a,(i+2)*sizeof(int));
                   }
```

Comment: Please define "too much memory". And what value do you expect `a[i-1]` to be when `i` is 0?

Comment: ok, and how can i do it in alternative?

Comment: Do what? To fix the `a[i-1]` problem you can change the loop from `while` to `do/while`.

Comment: nono, i don't want use the string, i want use the number

Comment: i need a alternative way to do a dynamic array using a terminal value in iput

Comment: If you don't know the length of the input then `realloc` is a reasonable way to do that. So it's not clear what "alternative way" you are looking for.

Comment: If you corrupt the input stream by entering an alphabetic character, this program will break and potentially enter an infinite loop allocating memory until you run out.  You must handle input error and possibly terminate.  Also, you should double the size of your array in each allocation and not allocate again until you have filled it.  This yields linear amortised time complexity, and also reduces potential memory fragmentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not handling input error.  If `scanf` fails to read, your program has undefined behaviour which may result in it quickly eating up all your memory and then crashing.

It's also advised to handle `realloc` failure, and also not reallocate every single time around.

Putting this all together, and also avoiding adding -1 to the array, it might look something like this:

```
/* values are read into this buffer */
int size = 16, count = 0;
int *a = malloc(size * sizeof(int));

/* loop control variables */
int done = 0;
int error = 0;

/* temporary variables */
int val, new_size, *new_a;

while( !done )
{
    /* double the buffer size when required */
    if( count == size )
    {
        new_size = size * 2;
        new_a = realloc(a, new_size * sizeof(*a));
        if( !new_a ) {
            perror("Realloc failed");
            error = 1;
            break;
        } else {
            a = new_a;
            size = new_size;
        }
    }

    /* read value and finish on input error or if user enters -1 */
    if( 1 != scanf("%d", &val) || val == -1 ) {
        done = 1;
    } else {
        a[count++] = val;
    }
}
```